# Spring Data: Single Repository writing to multiple DataSources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm migrating from one database to another. For the duration of the migration I'd like to be able to write to both databases at the same time, ie perform the same write operations on both PostgresDataSource and SqlServerDataSource. Ideally I'd like to be able to flip DataSources on/off based on a feature toggle, ie at runtime enable writing to Postgres datasource, then change read operations to use Postgres, then turn off writing to SQL Server. I have a feature toggle system and I know how to subscribe to toggle state changes so this part is not an issue.

I came across this [Baeldung post](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-multiple-datasources) but as far as I understand it describes scenario when different repositories use different datasources but each of them only one. [This example](https://www.javaguides.net/2018/09/spring-boot-jpa-multiple-data-sources-example.html) seems lower level and closer to what I need.

Comment: That is simply not how JPA works. You would need to duplicate the configuration for both paths. You would also need a strategy on what to do if things fail on your second database. And this isn't something `AbstractRoutingDataSource` can help you with.

Comment: Using multiple datasources for different repositories is a different thing and replicating the transaction is a different thing. I am not sure how the transactions would work out. Are you going to discard data in Postgres at the end of this and re-run the migration script. How will you check if the data is consistent in both the databases. Which one will you consider final?  I would rather go for single database and run the migration script at the end of it or would go for a parallel run for pilot

Comment: I've remove references to Jpa and added additional example I've now found

Comment: As far as I understand AbstractRoutingDataSource would be able to help if I wanted to use only one DataSource at the time, but flip it with feature toggle. Does it sound right? That would still be useful

Comment: Handling transations... would be open to thinking through different options. There is Jta? and I could look into logging failed modifications and fixing manually